# Possible bug with "unanswered" questions sort option

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In the past the **unanswered** questions would show questions for a tag that had no answer.  That doesn't seem to be the case any more.  Maybe a bug?

Example screenshot for the `javascript` tag below, but I noticed it on a few other tags as well.

[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selected the *need answers* filter. This filter [includes questions with bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261390/what-are-the-exact-criteria-and-their-motivation-for-the-filter-options-in-the/261392#261392).

There is an *unanswered* link in the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) description box that you can use to filter on posts with no (accepted or upvoted) answers.

Comment: Thanks now I understand how the filters work.  However, I will note that I selected the `needs answer` filter initially by clicking on the `unanswered` link in the description box.  Anyway I figured out where the filters list is now and the filter I wanted is `no answer`.  It might be confusing to call the filter `unanswered` in one place and `needs answer` in another (at least it confused me).  Since I thought `unanswered` would be synonymous with `no answer`.